# Why is explicit definition of attribute required when subclassing deque?

Tags: python, inheritance, collections

So I am subclassing deque for the purposes of raising a MemoryError exception whenever the maxlen is exceeded (maxlen is a default kwarg of a deque). I wrote the following class:

```
from collections import deque

class MessageDeque(deque):
    def append(self, item):
        dropped_message = self.popleft() if len(self) == self.maxlen else None
        super(MessageDeque, self).append(item)
        if dropped_message:
            raise MemoryError(dropped_message)
```

Now when I went to append items to this list, regardless of what the maxlen was set at I would get an `AttributeError: "MessageDeque" object has no attribute "maxlen"`

printing the deque would give me `deque([], maxlen=10)` which is as expected, but using `dir` would show that there indeed was no `maxlen` attribute.

After adding the following to the class everything appears to work as expected, although I would think that the code is entirely unnecessary

```
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    self.maxlen = kwargs.get('maxlen')
    super(MessageDeque, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: Your code, when inserted into a complete program, [works fine for me](http://ideone.com/iZjjRz). Please edit your post to include a complete short program that demonstrates the error. Please include the expected and actual output of your program. See [mcve] for more information.